# MS Botbuilder and SMS using Bandwidth.com

Tags: botframework

I'm developing chatbots on MS botbuilder SDK (4). My new client have requirement to create chatbot that is connected to SMS, I was using twilio earlier for that very well but they using Bandwidth.com, so I would like to know what are my options: as i get it botbuilder SDK dont have out of the box connection to this provider, but maybe I can use directline or other approach somehow?

Another option I see is don't use botbuilder and just develop c# web app using Bandwith API.

And in general I'm interested in how we can connect to custom platforms if it's not web-based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you have a few options. Here is a couple of possibilities.  Hopefully, others can chime in with more options for you.

One option is to build what is referred to internally as a "connector".  Essentially you need to translate what bot framework speaks [activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.activity?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) into whatever bandwidth.com speaks.

Another option is to build an adapter like [this one for Alexa](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Alexa).

Comment: thanks. If i got it correctly both options have much in common - core of alexa adapter is AlexaIntentRequestToMessageActivityMiddleware  where MessageActivityTextFromSinglePhraseSlotValue translates pure json payload to ms Activity class, right? So we basically have 3 options: 1) Extract just this logic and make translation 2)take a little broader aproach and create Adapter for needed provider 3)Give away botbuilder and just develop own abstractions to speak to provider. Given we have pretty simple flow which you would consider? Also which requirements do we have to provider api?

Comment: Also for all that cases i should still be using azure channel registration resource and use premium channel pricing tier or i can skip that?

Comment: No matter which you choose, there will be a decent amount of work involved.  I think option one is probably what I would go with.  However, if you wanted to build something for the community to use as well I would look into building something like the adapter.  As for your channel registration, I'm not entirely sure it has been a few months since I worked with MS Bot Framework.  My apologies, hopefully, someone from MS can give a better answer to that.